# i get Error executing child request for handler

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

my LogIn is partial view. i  pass a model that contain **some** fields of tbl_profile to partial view and fill it and then i pass filled model to a actionresult in  [HttpPost] part and ...
but now i'm trouble in  [HttpGet] part . i get this error on this line of cod **"** **@Html.Action("LogOn","Account")"**.
my code :

```
     [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult LogOn(string returnUrl)
    {

         using (var db = new MyContext())
        {

           var  AllFeatureToLog = db.tbl_profile.Select(u => new UsersClass.LogOn { username = u.username, password_User = u.password_User }).ToList();

            return PartialView(AllFeatureToLog);
        }
    }
```

class:

```
   public class UsersClass
   {
    public class LogOn
    {
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string password_User { get; set; }
    }
   }
```

LogOn.cshtml:

```
    @model MyProject.Models.UsersClass.LogOn     
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
     {
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
   <form class="signin-form">

     @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.username, new { @id = "username", @class = "input-block-       level", @placeholder = "* enter username" })
     @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.password_User, new { @id = "password", @class = "input-block-level", @placeholder = "* enter pass" })
     @Html.ValidationMessage("LoginError")

<label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">remember me</label>
<button class="btn btn-medium btn-general input-block-level" type="submit">   enter</button>
 </form>
 }
```

error:

```
     Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'
```

Comment: Did you try debugging to get the exact error that is being encountered.  The error you posted is a high level error indicating there was some issue rendering/executing the partial view.

Comment: i break point on [HttpGet] block . and it works true step by step .but after line "return PartialView(AllFeatureToLog);"             it  shows error :   The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.String', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'PakalaMaster.Models.CentricModelClasses.zUsersClass+LogOn'.

Comment: So the issue is your controller action is apparently returning a View with its model set to something of type `System.String` but the model type of the View is `PakalaMaster.Models.CentricModelClasses.zUsersClass+LogOn`.

Comment: yes i know . but why? i get a list in AllFeatureToLog and send it to view . i'm confused.is there another way to send some not all fields to view?

Comment: What if you try `return PartialView(new UsersClass.LogOn());` just to see if it will resolve the type issue?

Comment: no , it didn't changed.again same error . so, thanks for all your answers .

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead ::

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("LogOn","Account"); }
```

This will fix your issue.

Comment: i myself used @Html.Action("LogOn","Account") . but now i'm using @Html.RenderAction and it dosen't accept and shows cannot convert type volid to object.

Comment: @niknaz, it was wrong syntax, updated my answer. Have a look.

Comment: i changed RenderAction to RenderPartial .and now says :The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.String', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MyProject.Models. +LogOn'. is my coding in [HttpGet] wrong?

Comment: @niknaz, then there must be an error in your partial view. Can you post it's code?

Comment: it is LogOn.cshtml . did you want it?

Answer (score 0):

You sending List:

```
var  AllFeatureToLog = db.tbl_profile.Select(u => new UsersClass.LogOn { username = u.username, password_User = u.password_User }).ToList();
return PartialView(AllFeatureToLog);
```

But your View expectiong only one model:

```
@model MyProject.Models.UsersClass.LogOn
```

Change: your ActionResult on sending one: `var  AllFeatureToLog = db.tbl_profile.Select(u => new UsersClass.LogOn { username = u.username, password_User = u.password_User }).Fist();`

or View for getting List: `@model IENumerable<MyProject.Models.UsersClass.LogOn>`

Comment: no Andrey ,i tried it  before but didn't work. i tried IENumerable

Comment: @niknaz May be there is one more error but your View expects only one model, in other way it will generate error. Try to run your PartailView directly by path /Account/LogOn (without View, where it is nested) it have to show you certain error

Comment: @Andrey.Gubal Did you mean `.First()`?

Comment: i think my code has problem . when i pass a model that contain whole fields it works and i can see login page .but when i write [ var  AllFeatureToLog = db.tbl_profile.Select(u => ...  ] like above, this error occurs.